# One of the entities in my Core Data data model is not getting removed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to do Core Data migrations in my OSX app and I created a new version of my data model. In this new version I deleted one of the entities that I had in my previous versions. However, when my DB file gets created I still have it there. I deleted the previous versions of data model, where I had that entity, but it didn't fix the problem. For some reason the entity is still showing up in my DB file and messes up everything.

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?!

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: And you've chosen the correct Model version to be used?

Comment: yes I did, thank you though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add it as an answer as well.

You have to choose the model version to be used.

Click on your model file, and then in the File inspector, change the current model version.

[image]

Comment: Are you updating an app that is currently live? If not, delete the app and re-install it.

Comment: ok. Remove the app on the simulator or on the device and build it again.

Comment: thank you, it's osx app  :) I figured it out...just killed my data models and rebuilt them again